# Android run application on OS compilation

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have an Android Application which uses JNI calls. Now i want this application to boot with the Android OS(i.e. my application should compile with Android OS . I'm using Intel Atom board for Android compilation.). My Questions are as follows:

1) Do i follow the same procedure of creating make file and symbolic link with the Android OS NDK folder? If not how do i make JNI calls.?

2) I'm unable to understand the architecture of Android when i compile my Android Application with the Android OS. Can anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your application to run on boot time, you should make broadcast reciever, that catches on_boot intent. And from this reciever you can start your application via jni calls. But the lifetime of a reciever is usially short, you may look torward starting activity(or may be service, depending on your app) which makes the same jni calls. Makefile should be the same as if you follow ndk tutorial.